# Posso Utilizar o WordPress como Back-End

Tags: html, wordpress, front-end, back-end, cms

Eae galera, tenho um duvida frequente sobre WordPress e Web Design. Eu faço sites usando HTML,CSS E JavaScript/Bootstrap 4 , SASS e etc. Porem nao manjo do back-end , poderia utilizar o WordPress como back-end. Por exemplo, eu faço o formulario em HTML, existe algum plugin que envie todos os dados digitados diretamente pro meu email. Ou outro exemplo , uma area de login, poderia utilizar o WORDpRESS para criar uma area restrita de alunos ou etc? Obrigado.

Comment: Isso pode depender um pouco do Template que vc está usando, mas no Joomla por exemplo que tb é um CMS PHP é de boa criar uma área do site que é restrita para usuários logados. Tudo feito via MySQL e PHPMyAdmin, não tem muito mistério.

Comment: A pergunta não faz muito sentido, o wordpress, assim como outros CMS, é justamente pra criar backends de forma simples e rápida, não que não possa ser usado para criar páginas "estáticas" (serão dinâmicas, porém não terão uma parte de administração de conteúdo), mas não faz sentido

Comment: Você pode aprender a criar temas no worpdress, estude um pouco de php e como funciona o básico do wordpress e você já vai conseguir criar um tema e usar seu conhecimento de javascript, html e css.